Where to hoist state in a reusable composable that needs domain/business logic?
I have a very complex composable that is about payment. It can have multiple states (NoPaymentMethodAvailable and Ready) and have different actions (OnSubTitleClicked, OnBuyClicked, OnPaymentMethodChangedClicked).
Here are a few screens that demonstrate that:
PaymentMethods available

Change PaymentMethods (Dialog open when click on the PaymentMethod itself)

No PaymentMethods available + a SubTitle-Action

To construct this composable, some business classes are involved. Like the StreamPaymentMethods (API call(s)), GetPreferredPaymentMethod (local DB), FormatPaymentMethod (local),  you name it, class.
My question is basically, where do I hoist the state for this composable?

Note: The app architecture is right now based on each screen is a Fragment that creates a ViewModel and construct a ComposableView to display things.

If I would used this composable only once I would inject all the needed classes into my ViewModel, construct a State out of it, and lets that obvserve via viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle() (assuming the State is a Flow<State>).
But since the composable is used in 6 different screens, I obviously don't want to add all of the needed classes in each of those 6 ViewModel and basically dublicate code everywhere.
As a first step, I extracted a new PaymentBoxManager that encapsulated all of the needed classes and produces its own state (PaymentBoxState).
But now I struggling where to add this class.
To keep the "ViewModel is the source of truth and hoisting the state" argument, I could put in each ViewModel the PaymentBoxManager and using Kotlins delegate feature to observe the PaymentBoxState like that:
// ViewModel
class AViewModel(pmb: PaymentBoxManager) : ViewModel(), IPaymentBoxManager by pmb

// Fragment/Composable
val state by viewModel.paymentBoxState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
PaymentBox(state)

While having the benefit of hoisting it in a longer-loving Lifecycle (the Fragment) plus "having busniess logic in the ViewModel rather than the UI", I would have the downside of a bit more (annoying) code. Not showed here in the example, but there is also a bit of Dagger stuff involved.
Comparing to another solution a colleague suggested.
Instead of putting the PaymentBoxState into the PaymentBox composable, I could also put the PaymentBoxManager into it. The PaymentBox would basically work on their own and there is no need to put anything into the ViewModel anymore. Screens that uses the PaymentBox can simply put it to the composable hierarchie and are ready to use it.
@Composable
fun PaymentBox(pbm: PaymentBoxManager = rememberPaymentBoxManager()) {
    val state by pbm.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    // Use the state to construct the UI
}

@Composable
fun rememberPaymentBoxManager() = remember { SomeDaggerComponent().paymentBoxManager }

The benfit is cleary that I can just add the PaymentBox composable and "it just works".
Also, since the PaymentBoxManager is a plain Kotlin object, I can also test it Android-dependency free.
However, where I'm unsure with that is the following:

The PaymentBoxManager is now scoped to the composable lifecycle. It lifes shorter than the Fragment lifecycle. Being said, if I would switch the composable hierarchie (removing PaymentBox and add it again (for whatever reasons)), I would get a new PaymentBoxManager.
I moved some domain logic to the UI. (Did I?) Because the PaymentBoxManager uses the domain classes like StreamPaymentMethods that doing an API call or the GetPreferredPaymentMethod that doing some DB operations, but using it inside a composable, I feel a bit of "I doing it wrong".

So back to my question:
My question is basically, where do I hoist the state for this composable?
In the ViewModel(s) and dublicate (a bit of) code or in the composables?
Benefits and downsides are mention in this question.
Maybe there are even more I haven't discovered yet, but I guess these are the "main issues".
I also read the official documentation about Where to hoist state, Stateholders#business-logic, and Stateholders#ui-logic.
If I get it right, they basically recommend to put these kind of things to the ViewModel (what I second), however, there is no single word about reusing composables that requires a lot of domain/business logic.
There might even not "the correct answer", but just a bit of brainstorming from the community would be great.
Thank you and sorry for this wall of text :).

"I obviously don't want to add all of the needed classes in each of those 6 ViewModel" -- You only need one view model, just reuse it. Either the same instance (when you want to share the state) or a different instance for each screen. If the screens need additional state then use additional view models that are specific to those screens. There is not rule only a single view model is allowed per screen. Can you explain why that wouldn't work for you?

I was thinking the same thing as @Leviathan; why not just create a single ViewModel for the reusable composable and just re-use it across all the screens?
You could also have the re-usable ViewModel in place and a 2nd screen-specific ViewModel (if you need it for some single UI/action/etc. that's only contained in one of those screens).

Thanks for your suggestions! Actually, a new (single) ViewModel would probably also work. It would still require some setup for each fragment. Even less than putting it into the existing ones. The question that arises here is whether I need it at all. Would this be a better approach architecture-wise than just using it as a rememberPayementBoxManager? But I guess this is something I need to clarify internally (and with myself :)).
